# IE11 not displaying page

Tags: javascript, html, apache, internet-explorer

I have a localhost and I am testing an App, however, I cannot display the App only on IE 11 the same code works on other browsers.

First I got the error of document 7 then I added this code below to Apache:

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    BrowserMatch MSIE ie
    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge" env=ie
    Header append Vary User-Agent
 </IfModule>
```

Now I get no error, however, I still cannot see the App running.

[image]

I am testing an external plugin on my localhost.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Fixed Position Layouts</title>

    <script src="source-js.js?external-type=html"> 
    </script> 
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="source-class" id="022882ac_1540954478"></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

I just need it to render on IE 11 using my localhost. Need help here!

Comment: Page is displayed. You just don't have anything in the page. The only div in the page has no content. Go to DOM Explorer and you will see it.

Comment: You had mentioned that page is working fine in other browsers. Do you mean above posted code is just a sample and you have some more code in your actual page? If yes, then directly try to open that HTML page in Internet Explorer to check whether it get open or not. If it get open then it is possible that you have some hosting related issue. Also try to add some other HTML code in above sample and check whether it get display or not. As we can see page is loading in Internet Explorer.